# ReactiveUI OneWayBind leaks handles

Tags: c#, idisposable, reactiveui

I have a simple ViewModel:

```
public class MeetingPageViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
    public MeetingPageViewModel(IScreen hs, IMeetingRef mRef)
    {
        HostScreen = hs;
        _backing = "hi there";
    }

    public IScreen HostScreen { get; private set; }

    public string MeetingTitle
    {
        get { return _backing; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _backing, value); }
    }
    string _backing;

    public string UrlPathSegment
    {
        get { return "/meeting"; }
    }
}
```

And I bind to the MeetingTitle a TextBlock:

```
public sealed partial class MeetingPage : Page, IViewFor<MeetingPageViewModel>
{
    public MeetingPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Bind everything together we need.
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.MeetingTitle, y => y.MeetingTitle.Text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stash the view model
    /// </summary>
    public MeetingPageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MeetingPageViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MeetingPageViewModel), typeof(MeetingPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (MeetingPageViewModel)value; }
    }
}
```

After navigating back to the previous screen MeetingPageViewModel isn't garbage collected. I'm using 6.4.1 of RxUI and VS2013 (and the memory analysis analyze tool). If I dispose of the return value from OneWayBind then everything is cleaned up properly - but of course, I no longer have the bindings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the problem is the DependencyProperty ViewModel. Its lifetime is forever (note the "static" in its declaration). As a result, the binding that is attached to it is never garbage collected, since it never goes away, and that binding then holds a reference to both the view and viewmodel, and so they never go away.

The only way to break this is explicitly clean up the bindings. RxUI provides the WhenActivated method to help with this. Surround the bindings in a lambda, and use the provided function to track the IDisposals. When the view goes away this will then be cleaned up.

```
this.WhenActivated(disposeOfMe => {
    disposeOfMe (this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.MeetingTitle, y => y.MeetingTitle.Text));
});
```

Comment: What does "goes away" mean exactly?

Comment: When the reactive system disposes of the view.

Comment: when does it dispose of the view? (should i be going to github and starting to dig through to answer my question?)

Comment: You might. When I was doing this I set a break point at the disposal, and I seem to remember it being during the navagation call at the upper level. But more specific than that I am afraid this was a while ago. Further, the toolkit has evolved, so it could be different.

Comment: I'm reading a book about ReactiveUI and it suggests that in WPF it is cleared in various circumstances, including when the view is removed from the visual tree, and that the behaviour can be customised by registering your own IActivationForViewFetcher. It sounds like reactiveUI is quite sensible indeed.

Comment: That is totally possible. I have never looked at it in that detail. As far as registering your own handler, that is a nice find, thanks!!

Comment: 100% recommend the book "You, I, and ReactiveUI" :)